# Dynamically create buttons tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have the following function that creates buttons and packs them into a frame from a dictionary. The desired output would be that whenever I select a different dictionary, the old row of buttons gets destroyed, however, so far the only thing I get is a new row of buttons written on top of the old ones. Could someone point me to the right way of doing this? I know I can use Toplevel and bypass all that, but thought using a frame below the main one would be more elegant.
Thanks

```
def unpack(**kwargs):
try:
    btn_frame.destroy()
    btn_frame = ttk.Frame(root)
    btn_frame.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
    for k, v in kwargs.items():
        ttk.Button(btn_frame, text = (k), command = (v)).pack(expand = tk.YES, fill = tk.X)
except NameError:
    btn_frame = ttk.Frame(root)
    btn_frame.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
    for k, v in kwargs.items():
        ttk.Button(btn_frame, text = (k), command = (v)).pack(expand = tk.YES, fill = tk.X)
```

Comment: Can you provide a more complete, executable example of your code?

Comment: sure, I will do in a bit

Comment: your `btn_frame` needs to be a global variable or a class variable so it is saved outside of the function you call, otherwise you cannot destroy it the next time you call the function

Comment: I am afraid still overwrites the buttons previously created rather than replacing them. Let me upload an executable bit of code so my question maker more sense. Thanks

Comment: Adding `global btn_frame` at the beginning of `unpack()` may fix the issue.

Comment: It does, thank you so much!